# Sorting an array using selection sort won't work

Tags: c, sorting

Why is this selection sort program i wrote not working
It does not sort the array. What am i doing wrong?

```
//This program uses selection sort algorithm to sort an array

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main()  {
    int arr[10], i, j, small, pos, a;

    printf("SELECTION SORT\n"); 

    srand(time(NULL));
    i = 0;
    while (i < 10) {
        arr[i] = rand() % 100;
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
        i++;
    }

    j = 0;
    while (j < 10){
        i = j;
        small = arr[j];
        while (i < 10) {
            if (arr[i] < small) {
                small = arr[i];
                pos = i;
            }
            i++;
        }

        a = arr[pos];       
        arr[pos] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = a;
        j++;
    }

    printf("\nThe array has been sorted\n");

    i = -1;
    while (++i < 10)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    getch();
}
```

The part of the algorithm to find the smallest element works
The outer loop is where i think i made a mistake but i'm not able to figure out what
A little advice would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: What happens to `pos` if the first element happens to be the smallest?

Answer (score 0):

You need a very small change in your code for it to work

```
... 
while(j<10) 
{
    i=j+1;  // change i=j to i=j+1
    small=arr[j];
    while(i<10)
    {

    ...
    }

    if (small!=arr[j])
    {
      a=arr[pos];     
      arr[pos]=arr[j];
      arr[j]=a;
    }
    j++;
    ...
```

Can you see why this change is required?